# USB - autorun a web address

Tags: windows, usb, autorun

Q: How to open a web site automatically when inserting a USB.

I currently have 2 files on it:

```
autorun.inf
start.url
```

autorun.inf contains 3 lines:

```
[autorun]  
ShellExecute=start.url
open=start.url
```

start.url contains 2 lines:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://cnn.com
```

Loads ok on a Vista machine, but does not load on other XP or Windows7 machines.

Any clue what to change?

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft stopped Autorun from working on Windows due to security issues. As Chris said, I'm surprised it worked on Vista.

The Microsoft patch may have also been applied to Windows XP as well. But theres little you can do to make whatever you want to run use Autorun.

Comment: True.TechNet blog post from 2009 gives some background information on the subject: http://blogs.technet.com/b/mmpc/archive/2009/04/28/windows-addresses-the-changing-autorun-threat-environment.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[SamLogic article](http://www.samlogic.net/articles/autorun-usb-flash-drive-windows-7.htm) suggests two possible options, but they are rather workarounds than real fixes:

- use a USB-drive with firmware that presents the drive as a CD (e.g. [U3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U3#U3_disk_mounting:_hardware_emulation))
- create a program that scans for inserted USB-drives