# Setup a USB to prompt to go to a site

Tags: google-chrome, usb, chromebook, google-chrome-os

I was exploring all the Chrome URLs on my Chromebook, and I stumbled upon the USB internals. I saw that there was an option to add a test device. As curious as I was, I created one, noticing that there was a URL bar too, which doesn't make sense. When I added it, a notification on my Chromebook said that the USB was detected and to go to the site I inputted. That got me curious even more about what I could do.
Here is the image of what the notification looks like:
[image: Notification]

Question:

First of all, what is that feature meant for? Can I make my own and run it on my Chromebook? I tried to research how to do that, but no luck. I was thinking of making a physical USB that replicates what happened with that test device and then continue doing stuff from there.

Comment: It's surprising Chrome allows autorun of USB - MS dropped that from Windows for security reasons - https://superuser.com/questions/221889/usb-autorun-a-web-address

Comment: @DrMoishePippik It could be possible that ChromeOS doesn't allow it, but only allows it for test devices.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, So I found that this feature is related to a WebUSB. It is mainly for sending you to sites to manage the USB. The site is for testing using virtual WebUSBs. There might be a way to edit the USB's internals(correct me if I'm wrong) to set it up to do that feature. I will further test it to see what I can do.